# Make the matrix symmetrical, with units on the diagonal

Tags: r, matrix

My data:

```
data = structure(list(st1 = c(7L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 9L), st2 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
1L), group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

I use nominalSymmetryTest in order to compare the categories of data in my columns, but for this the matrix must be symmetric.

the code itself:

```
combination <- list(c(1, 2))

wilcox.fun <- function(dat) { 
  do.call(rbind, lapply(combination, function(x) {
    col1 <- dat[[x[1]]]
    col2 <- dat[[x[2]]]
      contingency.table.1 = data.frame(col1,col2)
                        contingency.table.1 = table(contingency.table.1[c(1,2)])
                        contingency.table.1 <- make_symmetric_matrix(contingency.table.1)
                        contingency.table.1[contingency.table.1==0|is.na(contingency.table.1)] <- 0
                        print(contingency.table.1)
                        test.1 <- nominalSymmetryTest(contingency.table.1,
                                                      digits     = 3,
                                                      MonteCarlo = TRUE,
                                                      ntrial     = 1000000)$Pairwise.symmetry.tests
                        test <- nominalSymmetryTest(contingency.table.1,
                                                    digits     = 3,
                                                    MonteCarlo = TRUE,
                                                    ntrial     = 1000000)$Global.test.for.symmetry
                        print(contingency.table.1)
                        print(test.1)
                    
    data.frame(Test = sprintf('Group %s by Group %s', x[1], x[2]), 
                
               p = test$Comparison)
  }))
}

result <- purrr::map_df(split(data, data$group), wilcox.fun, .id = 'Group')
```

The function that makes the matrix symmetric

```
make_symmetric_matrix <- function(m) {
    nr <- nrow(m)
    nc <- ncol(m)
    if(nc > nr) {
        m <- rbind(m, matrix(1, nrow = nc - nr, nc = nc))
    } else if(nr > nc) {
        m <- cbind(m, matrix(1, nrow = nr, nc = nr - nc))
    }
    m
}
```

As a result of the comparison, the result is not correct

I need the make_symmetric_matrix function to place 1 on the diagonal and the rest 0.

Now it just places everywhere 1 to a symmetric matrix

UP:

now the matrix is augmented with a function make_symmetric_matrix it looks like this

```
  0 1 2      
3 1 0 0 1 1 1
5 1 1 0 1 1 1
6 2 0 1 1 1 1
7 3 4 1 1 1 1
8 1 0 1 1 1 1
9 0 4 0 1 1 1
```

I want the make_symmetric_matrix function to make such a matrix

```
  0 1 2      
3 1 0 0 0 0 0
5 1 1 0 0 0 0
6 2 0 1 0 0 0
7 3 4 1 1 0 0
8 1 0 1 0 1 0
9 0 4 0 0 0 1
```

I left units only on the diagonal

Comment: Could you add the expected output?

Comment: Why not just `diag(n)` where `n` is the dimension required?

Comment: UPDATE question text